How do I split an array of jsons using tExtractJSONFields Talend component?
Suppose a field contains this Json, (an array of 3 Jsons) -
[
    {"id": 1 , "name": "name1"},
    {"id": 2 , "name": "name2"},
    {"id": 3 , "name": "name3"}
]

I want to extract each internal Json to a separate record,
that is from one record to three records and each record contains one Json.
Can I do this using tExtractJSONFields Taland component ?
Thanks alot.

In your JSONPath you have to be at the root of the JSON using '$' and in your output column (records) you access the different JSON nodes with '[*]'
Configure your tExtractJSONFields like this :

And then you have a row for each record like this :

